# Interaction dummies estimates influence other estimates?

Tags: econometrics, regression

In page 311 of Gujarati Basic Econometrics, there's the following example for use of dummy variables, when we're interested in the interaction between two qualitative terms.

[image]

Shouldn't we have different estimates due to the presence of the extra interaction term?